# Firebase 3 Resetting Email Login Password After Facebook Authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

With the new Firebase 3 update, if I create an account using an email/password, logging out and then signing back in works just fine.

However, when I authenticate with a Facebook account that uses the same email as the above, the password for the above email no longer works after this.  Whenever I try to sign in using this email/password combo again, I get the following error...

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17009 "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The password is invalid or the user does not have a password., error_name=ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD}
```

I have 'Multiple accounts per email address' selected in the Auth section of the console, but they still seem to affect each other.

Comment: Alex, was this a Firebase.com project you imported, or a new one you created?

Comment: It was a project I imported from Firebase.com, but as I mentioned in the answer below, everything was solved when I started a new project from console.firebase.google.com.  If you want more details on the specific project, I'm happy to provide info on or access to the specific project if you can reach out directly to me somehow.

Comment: Thank you Alex! It would be great if you could email me at alfongj-at-google-dot-com with your problematic project's details so we can take a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this! Originally I just transferred my app from the old console and was using 'signInWithEmail'.  I just deleted my app on the new Firebase console, started a new one, and used FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider and 'signInWithCredential' instead and everything seems to be working now.

Comment: Give this man a golden medal!
Thank you!